# How to execute sahi scripts with ant

Tags: sahi

I am currently executing my sahi scripts from Sahi controller but I am looking to better methods for executing Sahi scripts in batch mode, has anyone done this before? Please share your experiences

Answer (score 0):

I would say with a better google search or a search on stackoverflow, you can come to this answer:

[How to run Sahi tests as part of a Hudson build?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4140986/how-to-run-sahi-tests-as-part-of-a-hudson-build)

Its mentioned on the Sahi website as well about running Sahi scripts as ant tasks.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer running tests with the Java TestRunner. You call it from console like

```
java -cp $SAHI_HOME/lib/ant-sahi.jar net.sf.sahi.test.TestRunner \
-test $SUITE_OR_TEST_SCRIPT \
-browserType $BROWSER_FROM_YOUR_BROWSERS_XML \
-baseURL http://sahi.example.com/_s_/dyn/Driver_initialized \
-host localhost \
-port 9999 \
-threads 1 \
-useSingleSession false \
-htmlLog true
```

Have a look at http://sahi.co.in/w/Running+multiple+tests+in+batch+mode for a full documentation on how to run tests and suites from command line.

Regards
Wormi

Answer (score 0):

There are two solutions by you can execute Sahi script from command line.

1) Sahi Pro provides **Testrunner** by which you can execute your script.

For running script from **Testrunner**, open the Sahi Controller and click on **bin** link (or open the < Sahi Pro >/userdata/bin folder) and run the **TestRunner.bat** file, which will provides you information about how to run scripts from **Testrunner**.

2) If you want to use **Ant** for executing sahi scripts then you can generate Ant target from Sahi editor view.

For that open sahi editor and click on **playback**, which will open  Playback Properties from which you can create Ant target.

Let's say copy the ant target in **demo.xml** file and run the following command: ***ant -f path-to-demo.xml***